# “Must be connected to a terminal.” in screen

Tags: bash, debian, display, crontab

I'am using a script for an automatic server restarts after crashes etc. It's a fiveM(GTA V) server. Everything is workin on crontab, and there are some lines in this script to check out if server is crashed, and another to restart at given time.

```
*/1 * * * * bash /home/mudzy/AutomaticLinuxReboot/CheckCrashServer.sh >> /home/mudzy/fxreload/fxreloadlog
00 12 * * * bash /home/mudzy/AutomaticLinuxReboot/reload_fxserver.sh >> /home/mudzy/fxreload/fxreloadlog
```

Problem is about this line :

```
screen -S "Game Server" -L /home/mudzy/ServerLog/`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'.txt` -d -m bash /home/mudzy/AutomaticLinuxReboot/RunServer.sh
```

Screen refers to a script, where server is restarting. While executing this line, there's an error :

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

Does anyone know what should I do to make it work? I'll bre really grateful for any advices, help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to force the allocation of a terminal by putting something like `ssh -t localhost` before the `screen` command?

Answer (score 2):

I changed line with screen to:

```
screen -d -m -L -Logfile ServerLog/`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'.txt` -S "Game Server" bash /home/mudzy/AutomaticLinuxReboot/RunServer.sh
```

And now its works